# Eclipse Neon remote search results unreadable

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-neon

Does anyone know how to reset or select the font for the Remote Search outputs window in Eclipse.  I'm running on Ubuntu 16.04 with Eclipse Neon.  Running in a Virtual Box if that could matter.  It looks to me like either the font size is too big or the line height is being set too small.

Answer (score 0):

The options in Remote Search output window allows selecting the columns for display.  After selecting and removing several columns the text is new readable.

Comment: No.  incorrect.  It was only readable until the next search... :(